# Loss of Resolution using Display Port Adapter

Tags: windows-7, screen, resolution, screen-resolution, vga

I have a Laptop running Windows 7, set up to connect to two Asus Monitors.
My Laptop (Lenovo) only has one VGA and One Display Port.
When hooking up these monitors I must use a Display Port to VGA adapter. Both Monitors go to different KVM Switches which connect to the Monitors.

Monitor A. It appears that the Monitor connected through the display port adapter shows a generic name LCD_VGA and has a (recommended) resolution which is max of 1280X1024
Monitor B. The other monitor shows a correct name ASUS VS238 and a real (recommended) resolution of 1920X1080

When I switch cables say A = Display Port Adapter and B = Direct VGA the Resolutions Switch. A = 1920X1080 Max and B = 1280X1024 Max.

I have tried Detect under Screen Resolution, a Computer Reload, KVM Context Switches, Installing a new 1920X1080 Driver for the monitors, and Using Custom Resolution Via Nvidia Control Panel. None seem to work.

Is it possible the Display Port breaks the device information communications somehow? Any other hints?

Answer (score 0):

you need to disclose what kvm switch(es) with your setup.  Looks like your kvm switch(es) did not do the EDID emulation via the DDC communication between the KVM switch(es) and your connected system.

But for sure, it is EDID emulation issue.